# How to deploy solid_queue rails jobs using Kamal

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, kamal

I am using kamal to deploy Rails web and jobs that run using solid_queue using `bundle exec rake solid_queue:start` Since the job runs and does not start a port with web service it does not pass health check. What are some other ways to deploy using kamal both web and jobs services.

Answer (score 0):

If you use **Puma**, an official [plugin is available](https://github.com/basecamp/solid_queue?tab=readme-ov-file#puma-plugin)
Add it to you `puma.rb`.
It will allow Puma to manager and monitor the **SolidQueue supervisor**: no need to add a new container for it.
We deployed it like this and works as expected.

Please **note** that, since Puma logs every transaction, depending on your solid_queue polling interval, your development log will likely be polluted with a lot of entries. To avoid this behaviour you can add `config.solid_queue.silence_polling = true` to your `development.rb`
Hope this helps.

Comment: This does not work for production. I understand it is good option for development.

Comment: @EncorePTL - can you elaborate? I'm not seeing any official documentation on not using this for production.

Answer (score 0):

I am using `web` and `job` roles on my deployment config and I disabled traefik on `job` since it doesn't expose anything, there is no need to run health checks on it:

```yaml
job:
  labels:
    traefik.enable: false
  hosts:
    - web
  env:
    clear:
      CRON_ENABLED: 1
      GOOD_JOB_MAX_THREADS: 10 # Number of threads to process background jobs
      DB_POOL: <%= 10 + 1 + 2 %> # GOOD_JOB_MAX_THREADS + 1 + 2
  cmd: "bundle exec good_job --queues '+urgent:7;*'"
```

in case you *really* want to add some health checks to your job process, check the documentation: https://kamal-deploy.org/docs/configuration, specially the "Using a custom healthcheck" part

you might need to update your job like this:

```
job:
  hosts:
    - web
  healthcheck:
    cmd: "bin/process_that_returns_a_non_zero_exit_code_when_healthy"
  env:
    clear:
      CRON_ENABLED: 1
      GOOD_JOB_MAX_THREADS: 10 # Number of threads to process background jobs
      DB_POOL: <%= 10 + 1 + 2 %> # GOOD_JOB_MAX_THREADS + 1 + 2
  cmd: "bundle exec good_job --queues '+urgent:7;*'"
```